# How to configure apache for subdomain on Mediatemple (dv)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, vhosts, mediatemple

I have a mediatemple (dv) account and when i setup a rails app, i normally create a file in `/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/conf/vhost.conf` and put the following contents in it:

```
ServerName mysite.com
ServerAlias mysite.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/current/public
PassengerAppRoot /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/current

<Directory "/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/current/public">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>

RailsEnv production
RailsBaseURI /
PassengerMaxPoolSize 1
PassengerMaxInstancesPerApp 1
PassengerPoolIdleTime 30
```

Then i use capistrano to deploy my app.

I'm now faced with the circumstance where i want to have a site at mysite.com, but also a test site at staging.mysite.com.

The test site will reside in `/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/staging`

How do i configure my vhost.conf file to handle 2 separate rails apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i figured this out so i'll share it with everyone.

You need to create a subdomain in plesk by going to the control panel for your domain, click the domains link and then at the bottom you can add a new subdomain.

Creating a subdomain in plesk creates these folders

```
/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/subdomains
/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/<mysubdomain>
```

I just put my rails app files in `/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/<mysubdomain>` and then in `/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/subdomains/<mysubdomain>/conf` i just create another vhost.conf file for my subdomain.

After that stuff is setup, then I ran `/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/httpdmng --reconfigure-domain <mydomain>` and `/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/httpdmng --reconfigure-domain <subdomain.mydomain>`